# NLB HealthCheck Failing for C# Console Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, nlb

How does health check works in case of Network Load Balancer in AWS? I have configured a NLB for my C# console application running on a specific port. However, the health check fails for that port ( I can telnet successfully to this port from an external network). I tested configuring a Nginx web service on the same server running on port 80 and NLB health check passes for 80/443. But it is not passing health check for port running console application.

Comment: It works by establishing a connection to that port. If it can, the check passes, if it can't, it fails. There's no magic to it.

Comment: What may be the reason the health check is failing then? Since I can telnet to it, establishing a connection should be possible

Comment: Could be security groups, could be Windows Firewall, could be IIS bindings - your NLB is likely reaching out to the instance on the private network, not the public network, so your external test shows the service is running & listening but doesn't rule out most network-related causes.